# Why does this load improperly the first time but correctly upon refresh?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So in my last question, I was wondering how to make it a circle, but now I am trying to resize the circle as well. For some reason, The circle does not show up as a circle (it shows up as the square that it is). until I pull it down to refresh it and it gets most of them correctly then.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    PFObject *group = groups[indexPath.row];
     //if(group[PF_GROUP_LOGO] != nil){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ // go to a background thread to load the image and not interfere with the UI
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:group[PF_GROUP_LOGO]]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // synchronize back to the main thread to update the UI with your loaded image

            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.imageView.image = ResizeImage(image, 60, 60, 1);
            cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.height /2;
            cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
            cell.textLabel.text = group[PF_GROUP_NAME];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d users", (int) [group[PF_GROUP_MEMBERS] count]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        });
    });
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what the `cornerRadius` value is set to on first load? I'd guess that the image view hasn't been sized so the corner radius is 0.

Comment: where in my file would I set that? not in my onLoad right?

Comment: Set a break point after this line: `cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.height /2;`

Comment: hmm yes, it did not break until I tried to reload it... is the async causing this?

Answer (score 1):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath`  is called on the main thread whenever the `tableview` needs to recycle a cell for display.

You start loading the image on a background thread and update the recycled cell once that completes *on the main thread*

Thing is, you can't guarantee that the cell hasn't been recycled by that point - especially if the tableview is scrolled before the cell is updated on the main thread (or even if `setNeedsDisplay` will be triggered on the cell).

If you wan't to style the cell before the image loads, you should do it in `prepareForReuse` with a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass - this way, the cell is ready before it is displayed.

Comment: so the only way to fix this is to use custom cells?

Comment: You could apply the corner radius before the image loads/load a placeholder image before the background etc but unfortunately the cell could be recycled whenever the view is scrolled. You really need to write some caching code (or use someone else's https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage ;-) )